# mongo-connector issue with solr

Tags: mongodb, solr

I have solr running on one server and mongodb setup as replicaset with primary on one server and secondary on another

I have installed the mongo-connector on the search server to sync to primary DB as follows ,sync command it hangs

```
mongo-connector -m db.test.com:27017 -t http://localhost:8080/solr/test -n test.products --auto-commit-interval=0   -d ./doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py`

Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-09-11 07:27:41,361 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2014-09-11 07:27:41,366 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8080/solr/test/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.011 seconds.
2014-09-11 07:27:41,368 - INFO - MongoConnector: Empty oplog progress file.
2014-09-11 07:27:41,371 - INFO - OplogThread: Initializing oplog thread
2014-09-11 07:27:41,372 - INFO - MongoConnector: Starting connection thread MongoClient([u'content.test.com:27017', u'db.test.com:27017'])
```

Comment: Is Mongo actually a replica set here? You do realize the oplog is only present when you have a replica set.

Comment: Yes its is .Primary is on the server and using in the commadn above and replica is on another server

Comment: Are you inserting any documents into your MongoDB replica set after starting the connector? Are there any logs beyond what you've provided? It looks like the connector has started up and may just be waiting for data changes.

Comment: If you've run mongo-connector before and are trying to re-sync from the primary, make sure you've deleted or renamed the oplog progress file (usually called `config.txt`). Then mongo-connnector will start from scratch, rather than from where it left off last time, which might appear to hang if there's nothing left to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same story: there are some entities in mongo collection, but mongo connector hangs and even does not perform dumping the collection.

1. **Double check mongo's namespace** (-n {dbName}.{collection}) and take a closer look at solr server log (It helps me when there were some errors with updates).
2. Keep in mind case-sensative properties + each entity must contain unique key (in case your own id, not mongo one), otherwise update will be failed.
3. Somehow compiled version of mongo-connector didn't work as expected for me, so I used invocation via python:

`cd C:\Python34`

`python Lib\mongo-connector\mongo_connector\connector.py 
        -m localhost:27017 
        -t http://localhost:8983/solr/product 
        -d Lib\mongo-connector\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py 
        -o NewOLog.txt 
        -n solrDb.Product 
        --auto-commit-interval=0`